# reuse stored pdf file into cache in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf, firefox-addon

I'm trying to perform an action that consists in :

```
1/visiting a pdf page (done)
2/having the pdf file stored into firefox cache (done)
3/have the local (user side) location of the last opened pdf (? not yet)
4/store this location into a javascript variable (? not yet)
```

how can i automate this process ?

Comment: Look at the _xul_ files for `about:cache` and maybe the source for https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/ to see which APIs you'll need.

Comment: @PaulS. i have already downloaded the cacheviewer firefox plugin and it is super, but i need to know if i can get the last pdf file cached in Firefox programatically , in unix command line or javascript ? thanks for the answer